# Eclipse doesn't recognize Pandoc on my Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, pandoc

I am using this library to convert markdown to html.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bitbucket.leito</groupId>
        <artifactId>universal-document-converter</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, when I run the following lines ...

```
        new DocumentConverter()
            .fromFile(new File("/Users/myuser/MANUAL.txt"), InputFormat.MARKDOWN)
            .toFile(new File("/Users/myuser/MANUAL.HTML"), OutputFormat.HTML).addOption("-o") // optional
```

Eclipse throws the following Exception:

Cannot run program "pandoc": error=2, No such file or directory

I have installed pandoc using homebrew, I am able to run pandoc from the Terminal (command line) and get exact results but not from Eclipse. I see that pandoc is installed at /usr/local/bin/pandoc on my local machine.

Comment: Error 2 means executable not found.

Comment: I see that /usr/local/bin in on my PATH, I have also manually added PATH variable to Eclipse Build PATH, what else can I do to make it available for Eclipse?

Comment: Build path is not the same as PATH.  I don't know this, but consider reconfiguring to use the full /usr/local/bin/pandoc instead.